# Move Div element from one to another when page scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen a few similar to what I am looking for but not exactly the same.

So what I am trying to do is move elements from within one parent div to another but only once the user has scrolled a certain amount down the page. So once the user has reached a point on the page the elements will then move to another and then fade in at the very top of the page.

So far I have been able to create the div element and get this to show at the top of the page but only once the user has scrolled down 600. What I now need to do is once this element appears to move other div elements on the page to appear within it. Not sure if I am explaining this very well or not!

So if you look at the code below what I want to do now is to move all of the div class "Test" to move within the element of "Top" once the user has scrolled down and this appears. And then if the user scrolls back up again the "Top" element disappears and the "Test" div goes back to it's normal place.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 600) {
    $('#Top').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#Top').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
#Top {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Top"></div>

<div class="Test">
  <h1 class="heading-title">Title Here</h1>
  <div class="product-price">Price Here</li>
    <div class="cart-container"><button type="button" id="button-cart" class="button">Add to Cart</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `.each()` `jQuery` method to go through all the `<div class="Test">` elements and then use `.appendTo()` to move each of them and all of their contents to some other element.

I also corrected `<div class="product-price">Price Here</li>` to this `<div class="product-price">Price Here</div>`.

**Here is the code:**

Note: I purposefully gave the `body`a height of `2000px` so we can test here (run the snippet).

```js
$(document).scroll(function()
{
  if($(window).width() >= 480)
  {
     var y = $(this).scrollTop();
     var div;
  
     if (y > 600)
     {
       // for each element with class Test
       $('div.Test').each(function()
       {
         $(this).appendTo('#Top'); // move the element and contents to #top
       });
    
       $('#Top').fadeIn();
     } 
     else 
     {
       $('div.Test').each(function()
       {
         $(this).appendTo('body');    // move to body
       });
    
       $('#Top').fadeOut();
     }
  }
});
```

```css
body
{
  height:2000px;
}

#Top {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Top"></div>

  <div class="Test">
    <h1 class="heading-title">Title Here</h1>
    <div class="product-price">Price Here</div>
    <div class="cart-container">
      <input type="button" id="button-cart" class="button" value="Add to Cart" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is working properly? Try to add a div below your `.Test` div like `<div>Below Content</div>` and then scroll. You will see the issue.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt I understand what you are saying, if needed the `<div class="Test">` can be put in a `container` instead of directly to the `body` which would solve the problem, depending on if it is a problem for the OP. The focus here, as I understand, is on the `moving of the divs`. You can check with inspect element to see that they really move. All divs with `class="Test"` and their content move to `#top` and back to `body`.

Comment: So that's not good for the practice I think. You say _**if needed the `<div class="Test">` can be put in a container instead of directly to the body which would solve the problem**_, So I think you should correct your answer because this answer will be seen by others user of this community too..

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt No, I don't agree. The question is **how to move the divs on scroll from one container to another**. This code does just that. Yours doesn't. It **copies** the **contents of the divs**  to `#top`, so the divs **never really move**, hence they even **still take up space up space** in the `body` since they don't disappear at all (they are at two places at a time). So in my opinion, your answer is off track. My opinion is only my opinion, the OP will decide. As of mine I will let it be as it is because I want to keep it simple, it works as expected so no need to change anything.

Comment: The question also says **_if the user scrolls back up again the "Top" element disappears and the "Test" div goes back to it's normal place._**..

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt my program does exactly that. Try an inspect element. The div class="test" never goes anywhere in your example and that is the primary request. **It takes up space in two places at the same time**. When we scroll up again, in my example, the div does go to it's normal place (the `body`). He had a simple question and example, while I solved with a simple answer. If this is not what he needs I'm sure he'll comment and I will edit. IMO there are too many possibilities to address them all. He didn't speak about other containers either.

Comment: What @Ivan86 detailed above works great. However, I now only want the feature to work on devices bigger than 480px as I don't want it to display on mobiles. I tried using CSS but this then just doesn't show the section at all either at the top or where it is normally displayed. I have seen something like ($(window).width() >= 480) but not entirely sure how I add that in to work. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: @wardy118 I edited and put the `if($(window).width() >= 480)` inside the `$(document).scroll(function(){` so now the scroll function will be called on all widths but the code will be executed only when the width is above 480px, so if a window resize occurs and you scroll it will check the new width and decide whether to work or not.

Comment: @wardy118 If you put the `if($(window).width() >= 480)` outside everything it will only check once for the window width and if the width is **currently** smaller it will deactivate the scroll, after you resize the browser it will not work. You will have to refresh the page to get it to work again. So see what suits you best, the two approaches work differently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`html()`** jQuery function like below

```js
if ($(window).width() >= 480) {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 600) {
      $("#Top").html($('.Test').html());
      $('#Top').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#Top').fadeOut();
      $("#Top").html('');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#Top {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 15px;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Top"></div>

<div class="Test">
  <h1 class="heading-title">Title Here</h1>
  <div class="product-price">Price Here</div>
  <div class="cart-container"><button type="button" id="button-cart" class="button">Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all of your help on this.

Comment: What @Ivan86 detailed above works great. However, I now only want the feature to work on devices bigger than 480px as I don't want it to display on mobiles. I tried using CSS but this then just doesn't show the section at all either at the top or where it is normally displayed. I have seen something like ($(window).width() >= 480) but not entirely sure how I add that in to work. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: @wardy118 add the whole code into a if condition `if ($(window).width() >= 480)`...See Updated answer...!

Comment: Many thanks @BhuwanBhatt. That has worked perfectly!